# DB2 Query issue - should I use Exists?

Tags: sql, db2, query-performance, sql-tuning

I have two tables with large amounts of data.

`ACTION_SUMMARY` and `ACTION_DETAIL`

Every user has one `ACTION_SUMMARY` row per day in my db, and zero, one or more `ACTION_DETAIL` rows per `ACTION_SUMMARY`.

I'd like to have a query that does returns users that have at least one detail record with an action type (`ACTYP_ID`) in some set of values.

Here is one example:

```
select
    AS.USER_ID
from
    ACTION_SUMMARY AS
    JOIN ACTION_DETAIL AD on AS.AS_ID = AD.AS_ID
where
    AS.DATE between '2015-01-01' and '2015-07-07'
    and AD.ACTYP_ID in (45, 25, 11)
```

`AS.DATE` has an index on it. However since there are over 2Million users in the DB, and each summary has on average 5-10 detail records, I'm running into a performance issue.

I was thinking of using `EXISTS` in this fashion:

```
select
 AS.USER_ID
from
    ACTION_SUMMARY AS
where
    AS.DATE between '2015-01-01' and '2015-07-07'
    and EXISTS (select 1 from ACTION_DETAIL AD where AD.AS_id = AS.AS_ID and AD.ACTYP_ID in (45, 25, 11))
```

Now, I have two questions:

1) is my query with `EXISTS` faster - as in will the sub query stop as soon as it finds something and move on?

2) How can I improve my query?

I have indexes on `AS.DATE`, `AS.AS_ID`, `AD.AS_ID` and `AD.ACTYP_ID`

Thanks

Comment: The first query return a lot more rows... 5-10 times the rows of the second one. based on your question details

Comment: Why are you generating an `Action_Summary` row per day (per user)?  Why not just use `Action_Detail`?  Oh, and [please use an exclusive upper-bound(`<`) with date/time/timestamps](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (the blog covers SQL Server, but you can specify fractional seconds in DB2 too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exists` shouldn't be slower than the `join`.  But, if you really want to know, then try running both.

```
select AS.USER_ID
from ACTION_SUMMARY AS
where AS.DATE between '2015-01-01' and '2015-07-07' and
      EXISTS (select 1
              from ACTION_DETAIL AD
              where AD.AS_id = AS.AS_ID and AD.ACTYP_ID in (45, 25, 11)
             );
```

The best indexes for this query are:  `action_summary(date, as_id, user_id)` and `action_detail(as_id, actyp_id)`.  Note that these are composite indexes with multiple columns.

Comment: So does the EXIST operate like I think it does - meaning the subquery in the exists doesn't need to return all values - the first one it finds the EXISTS will return true? OR does the subquery full execute and run to completion before evaluating EXISTS? - Sorry for the bad use of proper terminology

Comment: @NEW2WEB . . . `exists` should stop at the first matching row.  DB2 is a decent database, so I would expect it to be smart about exists.